# FMX FormVirtualKeyboardShown shows not correct bounds for Kboard

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In my android app i want the VKBoard not to overlap the edit control so i use the FormVirtualKeyboardShown event (from Embarcadero's example) to find the upper edge of VKboard.

```
procedure TTabbedForm.FormVirtualKeyboardShown(Sender: TObject; KeyboardVisible: Boolean; const Bounds: TRect);
var h,dh : single;
begin
    FKBBounds := TRectF.Create(Bounds);
    FKBBounds.TopLeft := ScreenToClient(FKBBounds.TopLeft); // topLeft isn't right
    h := PanelEdit.AbsoluteRect.Top; // h is right
    if h > FKBBounds.Top - PanelEdit.Height  then movePanelEdit;
end;
```

but FKBBounds.TopLeft.Y takes a value near the bottom of the screen.
What i'm missing ?

Comment: "What i'm missing ?" What version of Delphi you're using is one thing missing. This was a known problem that was (supposedly) fixed: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14004?jql=text%20~%20%22keyboard%20bounds%22

Comment: @Dave Nottage I'm using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo. The link doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work". Regardless, there's an issue with the virtual keyboard bounds in Delphi 10.2. I believe it was resolved in 10.2.3, or perhaps 10.3

Comment: It means that only shows the message "No issues were found to match your search". I have  Delphi 10.2 Version 25.0.26309.314